# What's wrong with my code? It says unresolved Identifier

Tags: swift, nsnumber

It says "use of unresolved identifier" for both `NSNumber` and `NSNumber`. I can't find a solution for this.

I should be able to create a program that will convert each number from a given integer to its equivalent word value. The accepted value should be `UInt16` only

```
public extension Int {
    public var asWord: String {
        let numberValue = NSNumber(value: self)
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.string(from: numberValue)!
    }
}

var value = 2500

if value > UInt16.max || value < UInt16.min {
    print("The accepted value should be UInt16 only")
}
else {
    print("\(value.asWord)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot import Foundation.

Try this (Swift 4):

```
import Foundation

public extension Int {
    public var asWord: String {
        let numberValue = NSNumber(value: self)
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.string(from: numberValue)!
    }
}

var value = 2500
if value > UInt16.max || value < UInt16.min{
    print("The accepted value should be UInt16 only")
} else {
    print("\(value.asWord)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the `if block` and `value definition` in a class?!!
like this:

```
public extension Int {
    public var asWord: String {
        let numberValue = NSNumber(value: self)
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.string(from: numberValue)!
    }
}

class yourClassName {
    var value = 2500

    if value > UInt16.max || value < UInt16.min {
        print("The accepted value should be UInt16 only")
    }
    else {
        print("\(value.asWord)")
    }
}
```