# Converting integer array into String array

Tags: swift

What is main logic trying to do **(from repeat loop)** ?

```
let digitNames = [
    0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two",   3: "Three", 4: "Four",
    5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"
]

let numbers = [16, 58, 510]
let strings = numbers.map { (number) -> String in
    var number = number
    var output = ""

    repeat {
        output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
        number /= 10
    } while number > 0

    return output
}
```

Strings is inferred to be of type `[String]`

Its value is `["OneSix", "FiveEight", "FiveOneZero"]`

Comment: Xcode comes with a *debugger:* Set breakpoints, single-step through your code and inspect the variables. Then you should recognize the logic  quickly.

Comment: if you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark!

Answer (score 1):

The whole closure describes how to transform a number like `510` into a string like `FiveOneZero`, as you may have already figured out. The `repeat` loop gets each digit of the number and inserts the corresponding string to the start of the string `output`.

The loop goes from the rightmost digit to the leftmost digit. By using `% 10`, we can separate the last digit from the rest of the number. The separated digit is then used to look up the corresponding string in the dictionary. This string is inserted to the start of `output`.

Now we divide by 10. Note that we are working with integers, so integer division occurs. 123 / 10 will equal to 12. As you can see, this gets rid the of the rightmost digit (we've already added the rightmost digit to the output!) so that in the next iteration, the next digit can be processed.

We keep doing this until the number after dividing by 10 is 0. This can only happen when the number before dividing is a single digit number, and that single digit was the last digit we processed.

Answer (score -1):

May be it help you try this one.

```
public extension Int {
    public var asWord: String {
        let numberValue = NSNumber(value: self)
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        return formatter.string(from: numberValue)!
    }
}
```

use:-

```
 var arr = [String]()
        let numbers = [34,32,455]
        numbers.map({($0.asWord)
            print("\($0.asWord)")
            arr.append($0.asWord)
        })
        print(arr)
```

Comment: How does this answer the “What is main logic trying to do?” question? –  Just dumping code (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50132763/1187415?) without explanation does not help at all.